# Conjugates of permutation group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone give me conjugates of $(1 3)(2 4)$ in $S_4$  i.e permutation group. 
I have guessed the solutions based on what I remember of class. I remembered that in conjugacy class of permutation group contain elements of same length. Thus I guessed $\{ (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3), (1 2)(3 4)\}$. Is my guess correct and also what I remember is right or just hypothetical. Any suggestion will be helpful plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remember it correctly: Two elements of the symmetric group are conjugates of each other if and only if they are of the same cycle type, i.e. if they are products of disjoint cycles of the same lengths.

Thus your answer is correct, these three elements form the conjugacy class you were looking for.

Comment: Thnx sir for clearing my confusion